# Condition on avg in a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
    a_field = models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='bs',blank=True,null=True)
    datetimefield = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amountfield = models.FloatField()
```

I want to count the number of elements of A per month where Avg(amountfield)=0
Here's how I did it but it doesn't work:

```
B.objects.values('datetimefield__month').annotate(Count('a_field',filter=Q(amountfield__avg=0)))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have currently wrong spelling of `models.ForeignKey` and inside it `on_delete`, and also set `null=True` to `a_field`.

Comment: does Avg mean Average here?

Comment: yes it means Average